# my node js application stylesheet not working when hosted on a subdomain in AWS

Tags: html, css, node.js, amazon-web-services, hosting

My stylesheet and js files work on locally but not when hosted on the AWS subdomain.
This is the URL of the subdomain https://domainster.com/uploader. I have changed all the routes to start with /uploader because I wanted to host on https://domainster.com/uploader.

[image]

Here is the link I have used in my application header which is working fine locally.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to create an application load balancer.

Application Load Balancer has more advantages

1. Savings on the ip of the instance in route 53 you set the alias of the load balancer and you do not have to worry if the ip of the instance changes
2. redirect HTTP traffic over HTTPS directly from the loab balancer
3. from listeners you can set paths

[image]